# Get difference between associative rows of two 2-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, array-difference

I have two arrays and these arrays contain information about `id`, `linklabel` and `url` in the following format:

```
$pageids = [
    ['id' => 1, 'linklabel' => 'Home', 'url' => 'home'],
    ['id' => 2, 'linklabel' => 'Graphic Design', 'url' => 'graphicdesign'],
    ['id' => 3, 'linklabel' => 'Other Design', 'url' => 'otherdesign'],
    ['id' => 6, 'linklabel' => 'Logo Design', 'url' => 'logodesign'],
    ['id' => 15, 'linklabel' => 'Content Writing', 'url' => 'contentwriting'],
];

$parentpage = [
    ['id' => 2, 'linklabel' => 'Graphic Design', 'url' => 'graphicdesign'],
    ['id' => 3, 'linklabel' => 'Other Design', 'url' => 'otherdesign'],
];
```

I'm now trying to compare these two in order to find the information that is in `$pageids` but NOT in `$parentpage` - this will then make up another array called `$pageWithNoChildren`. However when I use the following code:

```
$pageWithNoChildren = array_diff_assoc($pageids,$parentpage);
```

The `array_diff_assoc()` runs on the first level of the arrays and therefore sees that both `$pageids` and `$parentpages` have a [0] and [1] key so it ignores them and returns all the information from `$pageids` from [2] onwards. However I want it to look at the content of the nested arrays and compare those e.g. I need it to see which `id`, `linklabel` and `url` are in `$pageids` and not in `$parentpages` and return those values.

How can I get the `array_diff_assoc()` to run on the keys of the nested arrays and not the keys of the first arrays so the final result is an array that contains the contents of the [0], [3] and [4] arrays from `$pageids`?

Expected Result:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'linklabel' => 'Home',
    'url' => 'home',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => 6,
    'linklabel' => 'Logo Design',
    'url' => 'logodesign',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => 15,
    'linklabel' => 'Content Writing',
    'url' => 'contentwriting',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To check multi-deminsions try something like this:

```
$pageWithNoChildren = array_map('unserialize',
    array_diff(array_map('serialize', $pageids), array_map('serialize', $parentpage)));
```

- `array_map()` runs each sub-array of the main arrays through `serialize()` which converts each sub-array into a string representation of that sub-array

  - the main arrays now have values that are not arrays but string representations of the sub-arrays
- `array_diff()` now has a one-dimensional array for each of the arrays to compare
- after the difference is returned `array_map()` runs the array result (differences) through `unserialize()` to turn the string representations back into sub-arrays

Q.E.D.

Comment: that's so awesome! Thankyou! As an aside I don't suppose you could give a quick explanation of this could you please? I haven't used unserialize or array_maps before and I'm looking them up now but if you could give a quick run down that would be amazing, either way thanks again!!

Comment: I think I may have found the answer so for others reading this and who are curious I believe that serialize() turns the php keys and values into a string so you have a string in all the arrays of $pageids and a string in all the arrays of $parentpages. The array_diff function can then compare these strings and pick out the ones that are in $pageids and not in $parentpages and then the result is converted back into php vales using unserialize(). Exactly what I needed! Thanks again! :)

Comment: Thanks! I've just read your step-by-step and have also found some documentation and what you said is pretty much what I had understood from what I read so it looks like I've got it :) Thanks again, this was great!

Comment: nice answer, but this assumes that the associative arrays are all sorted the same (associative keys in the same order), otherwise this will not work as expected ...

Comment: This method helped me a lot, but in my case i had to take care of data type of every element in array, when the array its serialized, my id's in one array were int and string in the other, so not matches were found.

Answer (score 4):

Very nice solution from @AbraCadaver, but like I've stated in the comments, there might be cases when the elements of associative arrays are not in the same order everywhere, thus a custom function which will sort them by index / key first is handy:

```
function sortAndSerialize($arr){
    ksort($arr);
    return serialize($arr);
}

array_map('unserialize', array_diff(array_map('sortAndSerialize', $pageids), array_map('sortAndSerialize', $parentpage)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Right way https://github.com/yapro/helpers/blob/master/src/ArrayHelper.php

```
class ArrayHelper
{
    /**
     * @param array $array1
     * @param array $array2
     * @return array
     */
    function arrayDiffAssocMultidimensional(array $array1, array $array2): array
    {
        $difference = [];
        foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                if (!array_key_exists($key, $array2)) {
                    $difference[$key] = $value;
                } elseif (!is_array($array2[$key])) {
                    $difference[$key] = $value;
                } else {
                    $multidimensionalDiff = $this->arrayDiffAssocMultidimensional($value, $array2[$key]);
                    if (count($multidimensionalDiff) > 0) {
                        $difference[$key] = $multidimensionalDiff;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (!array_key_exists($key, $array2) || $array2[$key] !== $value) {
                    $difference[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        }
        return $difference;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Excellent answer from @AbraCadaver and very observing remark from @qdev. My proposal is just a small adjustment to make the already proposed answer from @qdev more portable. Assigning the function to a variable make it usable also inside class methods and so on.

```
$sortAndSerialize = function ($arr) 
{
    ksort($arr); 
    return serialize($arr);
};

$pageWithNoChildren = array_map(
    'unserialize',
    array_diff(array_map($sortAndSerialize, $pageids),
               array_map($sortAndSerialize, $parentpage))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simply, call `array_udiff()` to leverage a callback with a 3-way comparison (no iterated function calls, no serializing) on the rows.

This will still work if the rows have associative keys in different orders -- no sorting is necessary.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/U9bcn))

```
$pageids = [
    ['id' => 1, 'linklabel' => 'Home', 'url' => 'home'],
    ['id' => 2, 'linklabel' => 'Graphic Design', 'url' => 'graphicdesign'],
    ['id' => 3, 'linklabel' => 'Other Design', 'url' => 'otherdesign'],
    ['id' => 6, 'linklabel' => 'Logo Design', 'url' => 'logodesign'],
    ['id' => 15, 'linklabel' => 'Content Writing', 'url' => 'contentwriting'],
];

$parentpage = [
    ['id' => 2, 'linklabel' => 'Graphic Design', 'url' => 'graphicdesign'],
    ['url' => 'otherdesign', 'id' => 3, 'linklabel' => 'Other Design'],
];

var_export(
    array_udiff($pageids, $parentpage, fn($a, $b) => $a <=> $b)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'linklabel' => 'Home',
    'url' => 'home',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => 6,
    'linklabel' => 'Logo Design',
    'url' => 'logodesign',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => 15,
    'linklabel' => 'Content Writing',
    'url' => 'contentwriting',
  ),
)
```

Granted the asker's sample data does not indicate shuffled subarray keys, my sample input will disrupt @AbraCadaver's and @Lebnik's algorithms and cause them to give a different result than expected.  My snippet gives the same result as @qdev's and @Gruber's answers, but my snippet does FAR less work.