# How to check a element of array is present or not in another arrays of array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, php-7

```
$result = array();
    $A= Array
   (
    [0] => Array
       (
        [id] => 1946
        [name] => cook
        [pic] => cookpic.png
       )

)
$B =  Array
 (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1944
        [name] => driver
        [pic] => driver.png

    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 934
        [name] => developer
        [pic] => developer.jpg
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1946
        [name] => cook
        [pic] => cookpic.png

    )

 )
```

What I have tried:

```
   $result = !empty(array_intersect($a, $b));
```

I have two array, I used `var_dump` to show them and can see them above.

What I am trying to achieve is, I want to compare two professions and want `$result` array which will be unique. Now if Cook is not present in $B then cook should get pushed in `$B` array and this will become `$result` else it should not get pushed.

Comment: Can you show us your attemps?

Comment: I had tried to use array_intersect like `result = !empty(array_intersect($a, $b));` but its not working as there is array inside array.any suggestions? @Sfili_81

Comment: Please update your question so everybody can view your attemps and the result so we can help you

Comment: Most elegantly, use [`array_udiff()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71195049/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doing `$result = !empty(array_intersect($a, $b));` will just tell you if there is common elements between `$a` and `$b`

```
$result = array();
$a = array(
    array(
        "id" => 1946,
        "name" => "Cook", // upper case C
        "pic" => "cookpic.png"
    ),

    array(
        "id" => 1946,
        "name" => "cook", // lower case c
        "pic" => "cookpic.png"
    )
);

$b = array(
    array(
        "id" => 1944,
        "name" => "driver",
        "pic" => "driver.png"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 934,
        "name" => "developer",
        "pic" => "developer.png"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 1946,
        "name" => "cook", // lower case c
        "pic" => "cookpic.png"
    )
);

foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    if (in_array($v, $b) == false) {
        array_push($result, $v);
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

you could use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-diff.php) but it doesn't work with multi dimentionnal arrays. So you have to do it from scratch

EDIT:

```
$result = array();
$a = array(
    array(
        "id" => 1946,
        "name" => "Cook", // upper case C
        "pic" => "cookpic.png"
    ),

    array(
        "id" => 1946,
        "name" => "cook", // lower case c
        "pic" => "cookpic.png"
    )
);

$b = array(
    array(
        "id" => 1944,
        "name" => "driver",
        "pic" => "driver.png"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 934,
        "name" => "developer",
        "pic" => "developer.png"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 1946,
        "name" => "cook", // lower case c
        "pic" => "cookpic.png"
    )
);

$m = array_merge($a, $b);
$result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $m)));
print_r($result);
```

merge the two arrays and then apply array_unique using array_map the delete duplicates

Comment: Thanks. Pardon me, there is some changes in que. only diff is your `$result` giving me only that array which is non-unique, But what I want in `$result` is array should be containing unique array from both `$a` and `$b`. Like if I search for "cook" so my result array should contain all element of $b with only one time  $a's cook

Answer (score 0):

Use `strcasecmp()` Inbuilt function for comparison.And then use `array_push()`.
You can use Brute force method. But i am sure that you can get better answer from this.

```
$result=array();
$A[0]=array("id" => 1946, "name" => Cook, "pic" => cookpic.png);
$B[0]=array("id" => 1944, "name" => driver, "pic" => driver.png);
$B[1]=array("id" => 934, "name" => developer, "pic" => developer.jpg);
$B[2]=array("id" => 1946, "name" => cook, "pic" => cookpic.png);


foreach ($A as $key => $value) 
{
    foreach ($B as $key1 => $value1) 
    {
        if (!strcasecmp($value["name"], $value1["name"])) 
        {   array_push($result, $value);    }
    }
}

echo("<pre>");print_r($result);
```