# PHP array_diff for multidimensional array by multiple columns

Tags: php, arrays

I have two multidimensional arrays:

```
$arr_one = [
    [
        'param_one' => 'qwe',
        'param_two' => 'yellow'
    ],[
        'param_one' => 'xyz',
        'param_two' => 'blue'
    ],[
        'param_one' => 'abc',
        'param_two' => 'pink'
    ]
    ...
];

$array_two = [
    [
        'param_one' => 'xyz',
        'param_two' => 'blue'
    ],[
        'param_one' => 'abc',
        'param_two' => 'pink'
    ]
    ...
];
```

Each one of this arrays has around `20.000` elements in it. I want to see which elements (sub-array) -including all its elements - is in the first array (`array_one`) but is not present in the second array (`array_two`).

For this i've made this function:

```
function search_arr($needle, $haystack){
    $needle = array_values($needle);

    foreach ($haystack as $k => $v){

        if ( array_search($needle[0], $v) ){

            if ( array_search($needle[1], $v) ){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And i am using it this way:

```
foreach($array_one as $arr){
    if(!search_arr($arr, $array_two)){
        $unique[] = $arr;
    }
}
```

It works well for small arrays but in my case because each array has around `20.000` sub-arrays it takes forever to go trough all of them :(

Is there a solution that will allow me to check which sub-array (with all its elements) exists in `array_one` but doesn't exist in `array_two`?

Comment: If they're in the same order and keys are also the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354767/use-array-diff-assoc-or-get-difference-of-multidimensional-arrays/22355153#22355153

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld hey, thank you but this answer is not ok for me because it uses only one column. That is quiet simple but i need something that compares the whole sub-arrays.

Comment: @AbraCadaver thank you! That accepted answer is amazing and it reduced the time from ~600 seconds to ~10 :O